# Firebase Realtime rule using Identifier instead of UID

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Firebase's standard Authentication table contains the following fields (samples below):

```
Identifier----Providers----Created----Signed In----User UID
a@b.com       Email        1/1/1970   1/1/1970     abc78e1820001092
```

In my  Realtime database rules I can easily access User UID as `auth.uid`, like below:

```
"UserData": {
    "$userId": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $userId"
    }
}
```

In our example this rule would try to match the access to the value `abc78e1820001092`.

But suppose I wanted my `$userId` to be the same as Identifier (rather than UID). How would I write a similar access rule? The problem is, there is no accessible field such as `auth.identifier`, so I am unable to check for something like this:

`"auth.identifier === $userId"`.

Question: Is it possible, and if yes then how, to access Firebase Authentication Identifier in Realtime database rules (in our example that value is `a@b.com`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can:

1. Set the custom identifier as a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) on the user's profile in a trusted environment.
2. Then access that custom claim in the [`auth.token` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken) in the security rules.

Answer (score 1):

As I know about firebase this will not gonna work

Firebase **Security Rules** provide access control and **data validation** in a

> **format that supports multiple levels of complexity**

To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, you only need to use the Given Prams  OR Custom Claims to design your **Rules**.

As I know about firebase you can't use your Identifier in Rules

for further more about firebase check documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#realtime-database